# Ruby if else in array.each

Tags: arrays, ruby, if-statement, each

New to Ruby here.  I am attempting to put an if else statement in an array to send a string if a certain modulus == 0.  for the life of me i can't find it anywhere.  I am sure someone will find it ridiculously simple.

```
a = *(1..100)
a.each { |i| puts "three" if i % 3 == 0 elsif puts "five" if i % 5 == 0 else puts i}
```

Just not sure of the correct syntax.  Still new to ruby and am trying to learn the syntax.  Took a C class last semester and my brain keeps wanting to put in C syntax.

When I leave it as

```
a = *(1..100)
a.each { |i| puts "three" if i % 3 == 0}
```

it works fine, just trying to figure out how to add if else to it.  Help is appreciated.

The answers below were really helpful.  I am trying to take it a step further and call it into a function.  It keeps returning 5, and not "five", or 3, and not "three".

here is my function:

```
def array_mod
a = *(1..100)
a.each { |i| if i % 3 == 0  && i % 5 == 0; i = "fifteen" elsif i % 3 == 0; i = "three" elsif i % 5 == 0; i = "five" else i = i end }
```

end

and here is my attempt at calling it.

```
require "minitest/autorun"
require_relative "array_modulus.rb"



class TestArrayFunction < Minitest::Test


def test_array1

    results = array_mod

    assert_equal(100, results.length)
end

def test_array2

    results = array_mod
    assert_equal("three", results[2])
end


end
```

I was told it is not updating my array.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax of a conditional expression in Ruby is:

```
if c_1 then e_1 elsif c_2 then e_2 elsif c_3 then e_3 … elsif c_n then e_n else e_nplus1 end
```

where `c_1` … `c_n` and `e_1` … `e_nplus1` can be arbitrary Ruby expressions.

It is possible to use an expression separator (i.e. `;` or newline) instead of the `then` keyword to separate the parts of the conditional expression.

With semicolon (this usage is non-idiomatic):

```
if c_1; e_1 elsif c_2; e_2 elsif c_3; e_3 … elsif c_n; e_n else e_nplus1 end
```

With newlines:

```
if c_1
  e_1
elsif c_2
  e_2
elsif c_3
  e_3
# …
elsif c_n
  e_n
else
  e_nplus1
end
```

If you use newlines, you can optionally also use the `then` keyword, but that is non-idiomatic, too:

```
if c_1
then e_1
elsif c_2
then e_2
elsif c_3
then e_3
# …
elsif c_n
then e_n
else
  e_nplus1
end
```

So, in your case, the correct syntax would be:

```
# idiomatic
a.each { |i| if i % 3 == 0 then puts "three" elsif i % 5 == 0 then puts "five" else puts i end }

# non-idiomatic
a.each { |i| if i % 3 == 0; puts "three" elsif i % 5 == 0; puts "five" else puts i end }

# idiomatic
a.each { |i|
  if i % 3 == 0
    puts "three"
  elsif i % 5 == 0
    puts "five"
  else
    puts i
  end
}

# non-idiomatic
a.each { |i|
  if i % 3 == 0
  then puts "three"
  elsif i % 5 == 0
  then puts "five"
  else
    puts i
  end
}
```

However, for such a chain of `if` / `elsif`, it is typically more idiomatic to use a `case` expression:

```
# idiomatic
case when c_1 then e_1 when c_2 then e_2 when c_3 then e_3 … when c_n then e_n else e_nplus1 end

# non-idiomatic
case when c_1; e_1 when c_2; e_2 when c_3; e_3 … when c_n; e_n else e_nplus1 end

# idiomatic
case
when c_1
  e_1
when c_2
  e_2
when c_3
  e_3
# …
when c_n
  e_n
else
  e_nplus1
end

# non-idiomatic
case
when c_1
then e_1
when c_2
then e_2
when c_3
then e_3
# …
when c_n
then e_n
else
  e_nplus1
end
```

Which in your case would look like this:

```
# idiomatic
a.each { |i| case when i % 3 == 0 then puts "three" when i % 5 == 0 then puts "five" else puts i end }

# non-idiomatic
a.each { |i| case when i % 3 == 0; puts "three" when i % 5 == 0; puts "five" else puts i end }

# idiomatic
a.each { |i|
  case
  when i % 3 == 0
    puts "three"
  when i % 5 == 0
    puts "five"
  else
    puts i
  end
}

# non-idiomatic
a.each { |i|
  case
  when i % 3 == 0
  then puts "three"
  when i % 5 == 0
  then puts "five"
  else
    puts i
  end
}
```

Note that the conditional expressions (both `if` and `case`) are *expressions*, not *statements*. There are no statements in Ruby, everything is an expression, everything evaluates to a value. A conditional expression evaluates to the value of the expression in the branch that was taken.

So, you could also write it like this:

```
# idiomatic
a.each { |i| puts(if i % 3 == 0 then "three" elsif i % 5 == 0 then "five" else i end) }

# non-idiomatic
a.each { |i| puts(if i % 3 == 0; "three" elsif i % 5 == 0; "five" else i end) }

# idiomatic
a.each { |i|
  puts(if i % 3 == 0
    "three"
  elsif i % 5 == 0
    "five"
  else
    i
  end)
}

# non-idiomatic
a.each { |i|
  puts(if i % 3 == 0
  then "three"
  elsif i % 5 == 0
  then "five"
  else
    i
  end)
}

# idiomatic
a.each { |i| puts(case when i % 3 == 0 then "three" when i % 5 == 0 then "five" else i end) }

# non-idiomatic
a.each { |i| puts(case when i % 3 == 0; "three" when i % 5 == 0; "five" else i end) }

# idiomatic
a.each { |i|
  puts(case
  when i % 3 == 0
    "three"
  when i % 5 == 0
    "five"
  else
    i
  end)
}

# non-idiomatic
a.each { |i|
  puts(case
  when i % 3 == 0
  then "three"
  when i % 5 == 0
  then "five"
  else
    i
  end)
}
```

Comment: Your reply was extremely helpful.  I tried to ask a second question in this box but i guess they don't want you posting code in these boxes, so I updated my top question.  Thanks again man.

Comment: That's because when you have a question, you should write a question, not a comment ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use an `if` to qualify a single statement, but once you move into `elsif/else` territory, it's necessary to break it up like a normal C-style `if` statement:

```
a.each do |i|
  if i % 3 == 0 
    puts "three" 
  elsif i % 5 == 0
    puts "five" 
  else
    puts i
  end
end
```

Comment: ok.  I didn't know if I had to put an else inside the brackets.  I am used to C's using parentheses and curled brackets for everything.  Ruby hardly uses them from what ive seen so far.  But the |i| , is that labeling the following code as "i"?  Or is it a temporary labelling i for that block?  Thanks though, this is exactly what I was curious about.

Comment: @Mike I'm not sure you mean by "inside the brackets." The `else` is lined up with the `if`, just like it would be in C (minus the curly braces). Yeah, curlies aren't used the same way... they're used to define blocks in Ruby (similar to `do`..`end`). The `|i|` is just declaring the loop variable(s); each time through the loop, `i` will be set to the next element of `a`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the syntax.

```
a = *(1..100)
a.each do |i|
  if i % 3 == 0
    puts "three"
  elsif i % 5 == 0
    puts "five"
  else
    puts i
  end
end
```

Keep in mind that `each` will return `Enumerator`, but not exact value. You need to use `return` keyword to return value.
Here is the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each)

Comment: `Keep in mind that each will return Enumerator, but not exact value` what do you mean?

Comment: I meant that `each` will return unchanged array in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Please see if the below code helps

```
def abc
   a = *(1..100)
   a.each do |i|
       if i % 3 == 0 
       puts "three"
       elsif i % 5 == 0
       puts "five"
       else
         puts i
       end
     end
   end
```

=> :abc

2.3.0 :013 > abc

this gives the desired output in irb mode.

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you want to emphasize, that there is always a `puts` and just the output value changes:

```
puts(
  if i%3==0
    'three'
  elsif i%5==0
    'five'
  else
    i
  end
)
```